# WPF Group Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that loads a realtime live chart in a window,
But I end up having 10+ windows open on my desktop (as many windows as there are charts).

So my need is basically to group/embed all these WPF windows in a single window.

I tried [WPF MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/) but I had serious trouble since it requires the windows to be usercontrols instead, and in that case, my live chart displays but stays empty and does not refresh nor plots realtime data. Same behavior when I put my chart controls inside a Page instead of a Window (chart does not update). This is why I guess I really need to stick with windows at this point.

I welcome any simple & straight solution

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to have a last century MDI in your WPF application? I'd recommend to switch to other, less expensive and more flexible content arrangement. I'd organize the charts in some kind of scrollable or swipeable container, maybe with some kind of navigation or tabbing facility... If your users really want to have one or some charts in a separate window(s), let them drag the charts out of the main container and create separate window on demand (something like dragging a tab out of Interent Explorer).

Comment: This sounds like science-fiction to me. Do you have any particular frameworks in mind to do this ?

Comment: Now I am surprised... Aren't we talking about WPF, the Windows Presentation Foundation? It's got everything you need to do that...